# SQL Query not returning correct number

Tags: mysql, mariadb, database-schema

I am trying to create a query that does the following:

**Write an SQL query that orders countries by the number of cities they contain for
countries with an area smaller than a given area value and with a gdp larger than a
given gdp value. Include each country’s code, gdp value, area, and number of cities.
Countries should be returned in order from the fewest to the most number of cities. If
two countries have the same number of cities, they should be returned in order from
the largest to the smallest gdp.**

I have created the query that is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.country_code, gdp, area, COUNT(c.city_name)
FROM City c, Province p, Country co
WHERE p.country_code = c.country_code AND co.country_code = c.country_code and gdp > 35000
GROUP BY c.city_name, c.country_code
HAVING SUM(area) < 1000000;
```

but this returns the incorrect number of cities.

I have the following code for several schema tables:

```
/*Table describes different countries with gdp and inflation */

CREATE TABLE Country ( 
    country_code VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, /* country abbreviation */
    country_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, /* country name*/
    gdp INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, /*-- groSEELss domestic product*/
    inflation DOUBLE NOT NULL, /*-- inflation rate */
    PRIMARY KEY (country_code)
);

INSERT INTO Country VALUES ('US', 'United States', 37000, 3.8);
INSERT INTO Country VALUES ('MEX', 'Mexico', 27000, 2.8);
INSERT INTO Country VALUES ('CAN', 'Canada', 34000, 3.6);

INSERT INTO Country VALUES ('CHN', 'China', 70000, 0.3);
INSERT INTO Country VALUES ('GER', 'Germany', 67000, 0.9);
INSERT INTO Country VALUES ('SPA', 'Spain', 37000, 2.5);
INSERT INTO Country VALUES ('FRA', 'France', 43000, 1.2);
INSERT INTO Country VALUES ('ITA', 'Italy', 50000, 1.5);
INSERT INTO Country VALUES ('IND', 'India', 56000, 3.1);
INSERT INTO Country VALUES ('MON', 'Mongolia', 32000, 2.5);
INSERT INTO Country VALUES ('RUS', 'Russia', 74000, 3.5);


/* Table describes the provinces each country has */


CREATE TABLE Province (
    province_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, /* province name */
    country_code VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,  /* country abbreviation */
    area INT UNSIGNED, /* total province area in km^2 */
    PRIMARY KEY (province_name, country_code),
    FOREIGN KEY (country_code) REFERENCES Country (country_code)
);

INSERT INTO Province VALUES ('Washington', 'US', 400000);
INSERT INTO Province VALUES ('Oregon', 'US', 300000);
INSERT INTO Province VALUES ('California', 'US', 200000);

INSERT INTO Province VALUES ('Jalisco', 'MEX', 230000);
INSERT INTO Province VALUES ('Nuevo Leon', 'MEX', 130000);
INSERT INTO Province VALUES ('Yucatan', 'MEX', 430000);

INSERT INTO Province VALUES ('British Columbia', 'CAN', 530000);
INSERT INTO Province VALUES ('Ontario', 'CAN', 50000);
INSERT INTO Province VALUES ('Alberta', 'CAN', 48000);


INSERT INTO Province VALUES ('Guizhou', 'CHN', 428000);
INSERT INTO Province VALUES ('Shandong', 'CHN', 58000);
INSERT INTO Province VALUES ('Hunan', 'CHN', 89000);

INSERT INTO Province VALUES ('Bavaria', 'GER', 708000);
INSERT INTO Province VALUES ('Saxony', 'GER', 41000);
INSERT INTO Province VALUES ('Hessen', 'GER', 480000);

INSERT INTO Province VALUES ('Catalonia', 'SPA', 485000);
INSERT INTO Province VALUES ('Galicia', 'SPA', 85000);
INSERT INTO Province VALUES ('Castilla La Mancha', 'SPA', 67000);




/* Table describes the cities in the different provinces */

CREATE TABLE City (
    city_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, /*name of city */
    province_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, /* name of province */
    country_code VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, /* country abbreviation */
    population INT UNSIGNED, /* total population */
    PRIMARY KEY (city_name, province_name, country_code),
    FOREIGN KEY (province_name) REFERENCES Province (province_name),
    FOREIGN KEY (country_code) REFERENCES Province (country_code)
);

INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Seattle', 'Washington', 'US', 23030);
INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Redmond', 'Washington', 'US', 2400);
INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Kirkland', 'Washington', 'US', 22350);
INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Portland', 'Oregon', 'US', 33040);
INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Sunriver', 'Oregon', 'US', 4300);
INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Bend', 'Oregon', 'US', 54300);
INSERT INTO City VALUES ('San Francisco', 'California', 'US', 6300);
INSERT INTO City VALUES ('San Diego', 'California', 'US', 2300);
INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Los Angelos', 'California', 'US', 7300);

INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Puerto Vallarta', 'Jalisco', 'MEX', 4800);
INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Zapopan', 'Jalisco', 'MEX', 1900);
INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Monterrey', 'Nuevo Leon', 'MEX', 9200);
INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Santa Catarina', 'Nuevo Leon', 'MEX', 470);
INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Guadalupe', 'Nuevo Leon', 'MEX', 500);
INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Merida', 'Yucatan', 'MEX', 2000);
INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Valladolid', 'Yucatan', 'MEX', 480);
INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Izamal', 'Yucatan', 'MEX', 200);


INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Victoria', 'British Columbia', 'CAN', 2200);
INSERT INTO City VALUES ('London', 'Ontario', 'CAN', 2300);
INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Toronto', 'Ontario', 'CAN', 3500);
INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Ottawa', 'Ontario', 'CAN', 8000);
INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Calgary', 'Alberta', 'CAN', 3040);
INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Red Deer', 'Alberta', 'CAN', 5700);
INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Edmonton', 'Alberta', 'CAN', 300);

INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Guiyang', 'Guizhou', 'CHN', 40000);
INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Anshun', 'Guizhou', 'CHN', 23000);
INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Zunyi', 'Guizhou', 'CHN', 10000);
INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Qingdao', 'Shandong', 'CHN', 100000);
INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Jinan', 'Shandong', 'CHN', 9000);
INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Yantai', 'Shandong', 'CHN', 70000);
INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Changsha', 'Hunan', 'CHN', 100000);
INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Yueyang', 'Hunan', 'CHN', 5000);
INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Changde', 'Hunan', 'CHN', 57700);


INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Dresden', 'Saxony', 'GER', 53487);
INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Leipzig', 'Saxony', 'GER', 34739);
INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Bautzen', 'Saxony', 'GER', 73899);
INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Frankfurt', 'Hessen', 'GER', 73894);
INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Kassel', 'Hessen', 'GER', 48393);
INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Darmstadt', 'Hessen', 'GER', 38292);


INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Ferrol', 'Galicia', 'SPA', 493);
INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Lugo', 'Galicia', 'SPA', 2374);
INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Toledo', 'Castilla La Mancha', 'SPA', 9483);
INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Albacete', 'Castilla La Mancha', 'SPA', 234);
INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Cuenca', 'Castilla La Mancha', 'SPA', 2350);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Don't use the old join syntax any more: it is outdated almost 30 years now.

If you group then all the non-grouped columns your SELECT must be aggregated with functions like `sum()` for instance

```
SELECT c.country_code, c.gdp, sum(area), COUNT(c.city_name)
FROM City c
JOIN Province p ON p.country_code = c.country_code
JOIN Country co ON co.country_code = c.country_code
WHERE gdp > 35000
GROUP BY c.country_code, c.gdp
HAVING SUM(area) < 1000000
ORDER BY COUNT(c.city_name) asc, c.gdp desc
```